# Get the variable after assign

Tags: php, smarty

From the WHMCS development [tutorial](https://developers.whmcs.com/advanced/creating-pages/), I created a page success.

in the example code:

```
if ($ca->isLoggedIn()) {

    $clientName = Capsule::table('tblclients')
        ->where('id', '=', $ca->getUserID())->pluck('firstname');
    // 'pluck' was renamed within WHMCS 7.0.  Replace it with 'value' instead.
    // ->where('id', '=', $ca->getUserID())->value('firstname');
    $ca->assign('clientname', $clientName);

}
```

You see, there assign the `$ca->assign('clientname', $clientName);`.

But how can I get the variable `clientname` in there? I tried use: `$ca->clientname` and `$clientname`, all not works.

Answer (score 0):

You can access to this variable from your smarty template specified in the function `$ca->setTemplate('mypage');`, for example `/templates/default/mypage.tpl`:

```
Welcome, {$clientname}!
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a final answer, but I can push you in the right direction
use

`var_dump($ca);`

To see all properties $ca has. Maybe this will help you